# Android strings.xml apostrophe, date, and string crash

Tags: android, xml, string, localization

I am working on some translations in Android Studio and have hit an error.

I have a sentence along with a date in this format.
`\'Estimated Time: \'h:mm a`
This works great.

However, translating to French adds an apostrophe in the word d'attente.
`\'Temps d\'attente estimé: \'h:mm a`

This ends up terminating the string literal early and my date formatter crashes.

Is there a way I can have a sentence with an apostrophe along with a date format in my strings.xml file?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is info from logcat,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: t
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parsePattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1470)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1382)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateTimeFormatter.java:788)
    at com.brunswickbowling.sync.passport.extensions.ContextExtKt.getDateTimeFormatter(ContextExt.kt:41)
    at com.brunswickbowling.sync.passport.extensions.TextViewExtKt.setText(TextViewExt.kt:98)
```

Not sure why I get `Unknown pattern letter: t`, but when I remove the apostrophe in d'attente, it works fine.  Might be something

Here is the XML format,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <string name="format_waitlist_eta">\'Temps d\'attente estimé: \'h:mm a</string>
</resources>
```

**EDIT and Answer:**

Turns out a fourth `\'` was needed to not terminate the string early.  So the string ended up looking like `\'Temps d\'\'attente estimé: \'h:mm a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Comment: You say your date formatter crashes. Please update your question and add the error text and stacktrace from logcat. Also the line of code where error happen would be useful to help you.

Comment: How exactly are you writing this in XML that's causing that to terminate the string early?

Comment: @RyanM I have updated the question to include the xml.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vadik, I have added some logcat info.  Maybe it's due to the date format after that apostrophe since I'm getting that error?  Something's getting in the way, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use alternatives for prohibited literals in xml try using & apos; to replace an apostrophe and \ to neglect a special character so your string will become

```
\'Temps d\&apos; attente estimé: \'h:mm a
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal, I tried that but still have no luck.  The odd thing is I get the error "Unknown pattern letter: t" in the crash log.  when I remove the apostrophe though it works fine.